# Create json key value from table column name and data

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-json

Is it possible to create JSON key value from a table `SELECT` statement, where column name as key and the column value as value

```
declare @T table(Id int, ItemName varchar(10), CategoryId int, ItemDate date)
insert into @T
values(1,'ABC',100, '1/1/2020')
```

to return something as below

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "table": "tableName",
    "data": [{
            "key": "ItemName",
            "value": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "key": "CategoryId",
            "value": "100"
        },
        {
            "key": "ItemDate",
            "value": "1/1/2020"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have looked at selecting as JSON but stuck here

```
select *
from @T 
for json auto
```

Comment: The expected JSON output is not valid.

Comment: @Zhorov: mistake, updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use `VALUES` table value constructor and `FOR JSON AUTO`. As is [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) in the documentation, when ... *you specify the AUTO option, the format of the JSON output is automatically determined based on the order of columns in the SELECT list and their source tables*.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl (
   Id int, 
   ItemName varchar(10), 
   CategoryId int, 
   ItemDate date
)
INSERT INTO Tbl
VALUES 
   (1, 'ABC', 100, '1/1/2020'),
   (2, 'DEF', 200, '2/2/2020')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.Id, data.[key], data.[value]
FROM Tbl t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
   ('ItemName', CONVERT(varchar(max), ItemName)),
   ('CategoryId', CONVERT(varchar(max), CategoryId)),
   ('ItemDate', CONVERT(varchar(max), ItemDate))
) Data ([key], [value])
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Result:

```
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Data":[
         {"key":"ItemName", "value":"ABC"},
         {"key":"CategoryId","value":"100"},
         {"key":"ItemDate","value":"2020-01-01"}
      ]
   },
   {
      "Id":2,
      "Data":[
         {"key":"ItemName", "value":"DEF"},
         {"key":"CategoryId", "value":"200"},
         {"key":"ItemDate", "value":"2020-02-02"}
      ]
   }
]
```

As an additional option you may try to build the inner JSON for each row:

```
SELECT 
   Id, 
   (
   SELECT [key], [value]
   FROM (VALUES
      ('ItemName', CONVERT(varchar(max), ItemName)),
      ('CategoryId', CONVERT(varchar(max), CategoryId)),
      ('ItemDate', CONVERT(varchar(max), ItemDate))
   ) v ([key], [value])
   FOR JSON PATH
   ) AS Data
FROM Tbl
FOR JSON AUTO
```